# Angular6 move to top when router link changed

Tags: angular

I've tried to go scroll top when router link changed.
So I used `scrollPositionRestoration` in **Angular6.15**, but it doesn't work.

In **app-routing.module.ts.**....

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
  })],
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your root module

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

ngOnInit() {
   this.routerEvents();
}

routerEvents(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
        if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            return;
        }
        //!-Scroll Fix
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
}
```

so what this is doing is its subscribing to the router, and everytime you navigate it scrolls back up to the top

Comment: Can you describe another way?

Answer (score 0):

In .ts of the component you can use window.scrollTo

```
  scrolltop(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

In .HTML of the component

in .ts of the component you can add

```
<button> (click)="scrolltop()" routerLink="/your link"</button>
```